# Symfony 2 one entity event listener is running on every entity load

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.6

I'm new to Symfony and following [the Jobeet tutorial](http://jobeet.symfony.gr.jp). I have three entities - Job, Category and User. I have the following service listener.

**src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    ibw.jobeet.entity.job.container_aware:
        class: Ibw\JobeetBundle\Doctrine\Event\Listener\JobListener
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

**src/Ibw/JobeetBundle/Doctrine/Event/Listener/JobListener.php**

```
<?php
namespace Ibw\JobeetBundle\Doctrine\Event\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class JobListener
{
    /** @var ContainerInterface */
    protected $container;

    /**
    * @param ContainerInterface @container
    */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad
     */
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $entity = $eventArgs->getEntity();
        if (method_exists($entity, 'setContainer')) {
            $entity->setContainer($this->container);
        }
    }
}
```

I expected `postLoad` would be invoked only for the **Job** entity, but I found that it is also called for the other two entities **Category** and **User**. I only define `setContainer` in the **Job** entity. So, I got the undefined method for the other entities. My workaround is to check with `method_exists`.

Is there any way to run `postLoad` on a particular entity only?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners

Comment: I updated the answer below. I misunderstood in first place. That should be it this time. I tested it myself.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATED ANSWER

Your example is an event listener but, based on your description you need an [entity listener](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) so checkout example below.

> - An Entity Listener could be any class, by default it should be a    class with a no-arg constructor.
> - Different from Implementing Event Listeners an Entity Listener is    invoked just to the specified entity.
> - An entity listener method receives two arguments, the entity instance    and the lifecycle event.

**Entity**

```
namespace Your\WhateverBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"Your\WhateverBundle\EntityListener\JobListener"})
 * @ORM\Table(name="job")
 */
class Job
{
   // Your properties, getters and setters
}
```

**EntityListener**

```
namespace Your\WhateverBundle\EntityListener;

use Your\WhateverBundle\Entity\Job;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class JobListener
{
    /** @ORM\PostLoad */
    public function postLoadHandler(Job $job, LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        // Do whatever you want
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `$entity instanceof Job` is not different to `method_exists($entity, 'setContainer')`. The `postLoad` is run though for the unrelated entities.

Comment: @Sithu - More example added and I've been using that logic without a problem.

Comment: I think `doctrine.event_listener` is running on every page load, to not a particular entity. According to your edit, if `entity.listener.user_persist:` is only attaching to the User entity. we don't need to check `$entity instanceof User`. I'm looking for such entity listener rather than event listener as @tetranz answered, but I could not achieve it yet.

Comment: [Example](http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/02/18/symfony2-doctrine-2-entity-listeners/) and [Example](http://egeloen.fr/2013/12/01/symfony2-doctrine2-entity-listener-as-serice/)

Answer (score 2):

If you're running Doctrine 2.4 or later, you can use an [Entity listener](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/events.html#entity-listeners) rather than an event listener. That is triggered only by the entity or entities associated with it . I've used this successfully in Symfony although I don't have access to my code right now. Here's an [example](http://intelligentbee.com/blog/2015/02/18/symfony2-doctrine-2-entity-listeners/) although it misses the vital part of how you associate the listener with the relevant entity. I think it just needs @EntityListeners({"listener service name"}) added to the @Entity annotation block (or XML or YAML if you're not using annotations) as per the Doctrine docs. I'll check my code later and correct if anything more was needed.

Comment: This could be a possible right answer, but I was not able to make it working. I use YAML and `postLoad`, but `postLoad` is never called.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the Listener class must be placed next to to Entity class.
With a directory structure like this, and the following configuration it seems to work like a charm.

```php
# src/vendor/yourBundle/Entity/JobListener.php
namespace VENDOR\YourBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use VENDOR\YourBundle\Entity\Job;

/**
 * Class JobListener
 * @package VENDOR\YourBundle\Entity
 */
class JobListener {

    public function postLoad( Job $job, LifecycleEventArgs $args ) {
        .....
    }
}
```

```
# src/vendor/yourBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Job.orm.yml
VENDOR\YourBundle\Entity\Job:
type: entity
...
entityListeners:
    VENDOR\YourBundle\Entity\JobListener: ~
...
```

or if your prefer annotations

```php
# src/vendor/yourBundle/Entity/Job.php
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\EntityListeners({"VENDOR\YourBundle\Entity\JobListener"})
*/
class Job {
    .....
}
```

If you have to inject some service into your Listener, you have to add some similar configuration.

```
# app/config/services.yml
# or
# src/vendor/yourBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
doctrine.job_listener:
    class: Vendor\YourBundle\Entity\JobListener
    arguments: ["Path\To\Your\Service"]
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener }
```